# how to resolve java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to get inputstream from AWS url

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, exif, android-exifinterface

my main goal is to get the orientation of a image which I get from AWS, part of the code is to first get the imputStream for which I need to pass the URI, I am doing `Uri.parse(url)` to get the uri and when I try to get URI I get

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider

URL passed:

```
https://xxx-2.amazonaws.com/YRINWoUKBOW97VXvpnRelWioT2r2/6d95054e-8a6c-4a61-a4ff-18f63aa187b4/1/thumbnail.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-xx&X-Amz-Date=20220221T203050Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=1800&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJGEUAZB7E5XX6NPA%2F20220221%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%xx&X-Amz-Signature=d3839d925efc6fffff417e25af1e6bad28ed10ef27d1c4460d20470
```

error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://xxx2.amazonaws.com/YRINWoUKBOW97VXvpnRelWioT2r2/6d95054e-8a6c-4a61-a4ff-18f63aa187b4/1/thumbnail.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-xxx&X-Amz-Date=20220221T203050Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=1800&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJGEUAZB7E5XX6NPA%2F20220221%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d3839dffff925efc6417e25aff414d76b8ed10ef27d1c4460d20470

this is my code

```
private fun getExifOrientationFromURI(context: Context, url: String): Int {
        var orientation: Int = 1
        try {
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(url)).use { inputStream -> //ERROR IS AT THIS LINE 
                if(inputStream == null) return  orientation
                val exif = ExifInterface(inputStream)
                orientation =
                    exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return orientation
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` does not support `http` or `https` URLs, only `file`, `content`, and `android.resource` `Uri` values. You need to use an HTTPS API for your URL, such as OkHttp.

Comment: Hello thank you for responding, could you give an example please

Comment: I used `val inputStream: InputStream = URL(url).openStream()` instead to get the inputstream, is this correct

Comment: @BRDroid: That would work too.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare, one question I have is, when I try to get the orientation value it is always 0, any idea why that would be,

Comment: @BRDroid: I cannot answer that. You might try downloading the image on your development machine and use something like `exiftool` to see if it has the EXIF tag that you are expecting.

Comment: okay thank you, I will have a look